# Update a UILabel using string value from another class in Swift

Tags: ios

How do I used a string value from a function in a another class to update an UILabel on my ViewController?
Here is my code:

View controller:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, dataEnterdDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var auaTempLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let weather2 = WeatherService2()
    weather2.getWeatherData("Oranjestad,AW") 
}

**func userDidEnterInformation(info: NSString)
{
    testLabel!.text = info as String
}**

func setLabel2(information: String)
{
    auaTempLabel.text = information
}
```

The other class named WeatherService2 contain the following codes:

```
**protocol dataEnterdDelegate{
func userDidEnterInformation(info:NSString)
}**

Class WeatherService2{
var currentTempeture:String?
let targetVC = ViewController()
**var delegate: dataEnterdDelegate?**

func getWeatherData(urlString:String)
{
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let sqlQuery =  "select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"\(url)\")"

    let endpoint = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=\(sqlQuery)&format=json"

    let testString = (String(endpoint))
    getData(testString)
}

func getData(request_data: String)
{
    let requestString:NSString = request_data.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

    let url_with_data = NSURL(string: requestString as String)!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url_with_data){
        (data, response, error) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if data == nil
            {
                print("Failed loading HTTP link")

            }else{
                self.setLabel(data!)
            }
        })
    }
    task.resume()



}

func setLabel(weatherData:NSData)
{
    enum JSONErrors: ErrorType
    {
        case UserError
        case jsonError
    }

    do{
        let jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: .AllowFragments)

        if let city = jsonResults["query"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let name = city["results"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let channel = name["channel"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let item = channel["item"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let condition = item["condition"] as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            if let temp = condition["temp"] as? String
                            {
                                setTemp(temp)
                                **delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(temp)**   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    catch {
        print("Failed to load JSON Object")

    }


}


func setTemp(tempeture:String)
{
    self.currentTempeture = tempeture
}

func getTemp() ->String
{
    return self.currentTempeture!
}
```

}

The code runs fine and everything but I get an error "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I try to update the UILabel in my ViewController. 
When I used the `print("The return value is: "+information)` in the view controller class it print the return value correctly. 
This is the reason I'm confused right now because I don't know why I still getting the "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when trying to use this value to update my UILabel.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix this issue by doing the following:
I create the following class
-   Item
-   Condition
-   Channel 
These classes implement the *JSONPopulator* protocol.
The *JSONPopulator* protocol:

```
protocol JSONPopulator 
{
    func populate(data:AnyObject)
}
```

*Item* class:

```
class Item: JSONPopulator
{
var condition:Condition?

func getCondition() ->Condition
{
    return condition!
}

func populate(data: AnyObject)
{
    condition = Condition()
    condition?.populate(data)
}
}
```

*Condition* class:

```
class Condition:JSONPopulator
{

var arubaTemp:String?

var channel:NSDictionary!

func getArubaTemp()->String
{
    return arubaTemp!
}

func getBonaireTemp() ->String
{
    return bonaireTemp!
}

func getCuracaoTemp()->String
{
    return curacaoTemp!
}

func populate(data: AnyObject)
{
    if let query = data["query"] as? NSDictionary
    {
        if let results = query["results"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let channel = results["channel"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                self.channel = channel
                if let location = channel["location"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let city = location["city"] as? String
                    {
                        if city.containsString("Oranjestad")
                        {
                            switch city
                            {
                            case "Oranjestad":
                                arubaTemp = getTemp()
                                print(arubaTemp)
                            default:
                                break
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



func getTemp() ->String
{
    var temp:String?
    if let item = self.channel["item"] as? NSDictionary
    {
        if let condition = item["condition"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let tempeture = condition["temp"] as? String
            {
                print(tempeture)
                temp = tempeture
            }
        }
    }
    print(temp)
    return temp!
}

}
```

Channel class:

```
class Channel: JSONPopulator
{
    var item:Item?
    var unit:Unit?
    var request_city:String?

    func setRequestCity(request_city:String)
    {
        self.request_city = request_city
    }

    func getRequestCity() ->String
    {
        return request_city!
    }

    func getItem() -> Item
    {
        return item!
    }

    func getUnit() -> Unit
    {
        return unit!
    }

    func populate(data: AnyObject)
    {
        item = Item()
        item?.populate(data)      
    }

}
```

The *WeatherService* class that handles the function of parsing the JSON object. This class implement a *WeatherServiceCallBack* protocol. 
The *WeatherServiceCallBack* protocol:

```
protocol WeatherServiceCallBack
{
    func arubaWeatherServiceService( channel:Channel)
    func arubaWeatherServiceFailure()
}
```

*WeatherService* class:

```
class WeatherService
{
    var weatherServiceCallBack:WeatherServiceCallBack
    var requestCity:String?

    init(weatherServiceCallBack: WeatherServiceCallBack)
{
    self.weatherServiceCallBack = weatherServiceCallBack
}

internal func checkCity(city:String)
{
    switch (city)
    {
        case "Oranjestad,AW":
        requestCity = city
        getWeatherData(requestCity!)
    default:
        break
    }

}


func getWeatherData(urlString:String)
{
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    let sqlQuery =  "select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"\(url)\")"

    let endpoint = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=\(sqlQuery)&format=json"


    let testString = (String(endpoint)
    executeTask(testString)
}

func executeTask(request_data: String)
{
    let requestString:NSString = request_data.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!

    let url_with_data = NSURL(string: requestString as String)!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url_with_data){
        (data, response, error) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if data == nil
            {
                print("Failed loading HTTP link")

            }else{
                self.onPost(data!)
            }
        })
    }
    task.resume()

}

func onPost(data:NSData)
{
    enum JSONErrors: ErrorType
    {
        case UserError
        case jsonError
    }

    do{
        let jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
        print(jsonResults)

        if let city = jsonResults["query"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let name = city["count"] as? Int
            {
                if name == 0
                {
                    weatherServiceCallBack.arubaWeatherServiceFailure()
                }
            }

        }

        if let requestCity_check = jsonResults["query"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let results = requestCity_check["results"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let channel = results["channel"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let location = channel["location"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let city = location["city"] as? String
                        {
                            requestCity = city
                            let channel = Channel()
                            channel.setRequestCity(requestCity!)
                            channel.populate(jsonResults)
                            weatherServiceCallBack.arubaWeatherServiceService(channel)
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }


    }catch {
        print("Failed to load JSON Object")
    }

}

}
```

In the *ViewController* class (I add some animation to the UILabel so it can flip from Fahrenheit to Celsius):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WeatherServiceCallBack
{
    var weather:WeatherService?
    var aua_Tempeture_in_F:String?
    var aua_Tempeture_in_C:String?
    var timer = NSTimer()
    @IBOutlet var aua_Temp_Label: UILabel!
    let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.35
    let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 5  //10


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    weather = WeatherService(weatherServiceCallBack: self)
    weather?.checkCity("Oranjestad,AW")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    func animateTemptext()
    {

self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(7.0, target: self, selector: Selector("tempConvertionTextSwitch"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

func setTempinCelsius(temp_string:String)
{

    aua_Tempeture_in_F = "\(temp_string)°F"
    let convertedString = convertFahrenheittoCelsius(temp_string)
    aua_Tempeture_in_C = "\(convertedString)°C"
    aua_Temp_Label.text = aua_Tempeture_in_C
    animateTemptext()
}

func convertFahrenheittoCelsius(currentTemp:String) ->String
{
    let tempTocelsius = (String(((Int(currentTemp)! - 32) * 5)/9))
    return tempTocelsius
}

@objc func tempConvertionTextSwitch()
{
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(self.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {

        }

    }
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    if aua_Temp_Label.text == aua_Tempeture_in_F
    {

        aua_Temp_Label.text = aua_Tempeture_in_C
    }else if aua_Temp_Label.text == aua_Tempeture_in_C
    {

        aua_Temp_Label.text = aua_Tempeture_in_F
    }else if aua_Temp_Label == ""
    {
        aua_Temp_Label.text = aua_Tempeture_in_C
    }
    aua_Temp_Label.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    CATransaction.commit()

}



func arubaWeatherServiceFailure() {

}

func arubaWeatherServiceService(channel: Channel)
{
    let requested_city = channel.getRequestCity()
    let items = channel.getItem()
    let aua_Temp = items.getCondition().getArubaTemp()
    setTempinCelsius(aua_Temp)

}

}
```

Reference:

- *iOS 8 Swift Programming Cookbook Solutions Examples for iOS Apps* book
- *iOS 8 Programming Fundamentals with Swift Swift, Xcode, and Cocoa Basics* book

Hope it help the once that had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create delegate method.

In `viewController` you create delegate method and call it from where you get response and set `viewController.delegate = self`

I could not explain more you have to search for that and it will works 100% .

All the best.

Comment: Do you mean create an variable of type String in the class Viewcontroller?

Comment: Ok because I've done that already but still no positive respond. I don't you if you could post an example on how it can be done?

Comment: k when i'll free than i post example

Comment: which class you push after get string from response?

Comment: I want to the 'WeatherService2' to parse the JSON file and get the tempeture string value and used that string to update the UILabel in the 'ViewController' class.

Comment: ohh than `WeatherService2` is not a viewController type class its a simple class like NSObject in objective-c now i little understand your question properly because i'm weak in swift so code also not help me to understand.

Comment: For that you can create delegate method and implement it. now delegate method you have to create and its a 100% working. but i cant give you code about delegate because i'm not free right now for that i'm sorry.

Comment: @Melchior create delegate method its work 100% All the best.

Comment: Yes, the WeatherService2 is not a viewController. I'm trying to used the delegate but still getting the "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value",  Can I post the code so you can see were I'm missing something?

Comment: put your delegate method and code  in question so i'll check it.

Comment: in the WeatherService2 :'protocol dataEnterdDelegate{
    func userDidEnterInformation(info:NSString)
}'                                                                                                                            A variable: 'var delegate: dataEnterdDelegate?'

Comment: In the setLabel function I used: "delegate!.userDidEnterInformation(temp)"      In the viewController class I implemented the protocol: 'class ViewController: UIViewController, dataEnterdDelegate'                                   And implement the function: 'func userDidEnterInformation(info: NSString)
    {
        testLabel!.text = info as String
    }
'

Comment: If my comment confuse you see my code, see my code above I update it. The changes are mark with **